# Can I buy a vignette for Hungary (Matrica) online?

Tags: driving, automobiles, hungary, vignettes

I will drive through Hungary and I need a vignette. As it's an electronic one, I want to buy it online in advance and save some time. Is it possible? How much does it cost compared with buying it at the border?

Comment: Be careful to use the official sites as there is one or are more that sell the vignette for an extra fee and are less helpful when things go wrong.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Purchasing the E-Vignette Online

It seems that **the vignettes can be purchased after registering on the [website of the company currently managing Hungarian motorways](https://ematrica.nemzetiutdij.hu)**. You click on the icon of your vehicle and are redirected to the registration/login page.

### Pricing Information

Regarding the pricing, I could not find any information signalling different prices between on-line and off-the-shelf purchases. I am therefore assuming the prices are the same, and this makes sense since we are talking about an electronic vignette -- no shipping costs, etc.

Here is some information about pricing, taken from [the official Hungarian National Toll Payment website](http://www.toll-charge.hu/Toll-tariffs/Pricing/):

> The amount of the toll depends on the category of the motor vehicle. The toll categories are as follows:
>
> - D1: motorcycles, and motor vehicles with a maximum total permissible weight of 3.5 tons, including any trailers.
> - B2: buses and campers (with trailers) with a maximum total permissible weight over 3.5 tons.

As of December 2014, the prices are (adapted from [this site](https://ematrica.nemzetiutdij.hu)):
[image: Hungarian E-Vignette Prices]

Comment: It is indeed possible. I bought a vignette online myself just a month ago.

Answer (score 4):

The URL of the official web-site to buy vignette in Hungary had changed to https://ematrica.nemzetiutdij.hu